# Dataframe does not recognize month and day order

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Excel file like this:

[image]

The format date is MM/DD/YYYY. Although when I try to read it with pandas, it changes the date format and gets weird:

```
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
df
Out[21]: 
   ID                 Date
0   1  2022-07-08 00:00:00
1   2           04/18/2022
```

If I try to change the format with to_datetime, the month and day for the first sample invert and it is not the same as excel file:

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"]).dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
   ID        Date
0   1  07-08-2022
1   2  04-18-2022
```

How could I see these dates in my dataframe with the excel format (MM/DD/YYYY)?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the date is not incorrectly set in excel? By default `read_excel` does not force to parse dates.

Comment: try passing `format='%m/%d/%Y'` to pd.to_datetime

Comment: I tried @NicholasHansen-Feruch, but it didn't work. mosway is probably right. It is an problem I should solve on Excel. I will delete my question. Thanks guys

Comment: @user026 don't delete the question, for other people who may have the same problem! But glad you identified a possible solution